# run a sql depending on Oracle DB version

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i need to run the following SQL on all databases which have the version 11 of oracle.

```
select USERNAME,SYSDBA,SYSOPER,SYSASM from from v$pwfile_users
```

For finding the DB version :

```
SQL> SELECT distinct version FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;
VERSION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11.2.0.4.0
```

So only when the version starts with '11.' i will have to run the query.
How can i do this in a single SQL query?may be using a 'case'?

Comment: can you write your own pl/sql functions to wrap version check?

Comment: What client are you going to use? Sqlplus?sqlcl/ Sql developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with ver as
  (select distinct substr(version, 1, 2) version
   from product_component_version
  )
select USERNAME,SYSDBA,SYSOPER,SYSASM  
From v$pwfile_users 
where exists (select null from ver where version = '11');
```

Comment: How can i run "select USERNAME, SYSDBA, SYSOPER, SYSASM, SYSBACKUP, SYSDG, SYSKM, CON_ID from v$pwfile_users" when the version is not 11

Comment: Adjust WHERE clause to include other versions. Or, if you want to run it unconditionally, just run the very first SELECT you posted in this question - it doesn't care about *versions*.